# TFSSecurity - Create Tag Definition Permission not settable

Tags: tfs, permissions, tfs-security

Within TFSSecurity's [reference page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) for permissions, under **Team project level**, there is a list of permissions and their corresponding actions. Using TFSSecurity, I was able to set all of the permissions at the project-level for a new group I created, except for *Create Tag Definition*. You can almost expect the error, with it's action being in upper and lower-case letters (*Create*), while every other action is in all upper-case letters (*PUBLISH_TEST_RESULTS*, *DELETE*, *DELETE_TEST_RESULTS*).

I've tried using *create*, *Create*, and *CREATE*, none of these work. Does anybody know the corresponding action for this permission, since it is not documented online by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **specify the team project Guid** instead of the team project name in the command.

Please follow below steps to set the `Create Tag Definition` permission for team project groups:

1. Get the team project ID with REST API:

   `http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{YourProjectName}?api-version=1.0`
2. cd to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools`
   (based on your TFS version), run below command:

   `TFSSecurity /a+ Tagging //6553c041-5e50-4ace-bec2-c1dba2b812ca Create 0825 ALLOW /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

PS: In this example the
    team project ID is `6553c041-5e50-4ace-bec2-c1dba2b812ca` and the
    user group name is `0825` , **don't forget to add '//' in front of the  team project ID**

[image]